# Drupal 8. Imce module show thumbnails instead of a filename

Tags: files

Is it possibility to show thumbnails instead of a filename in imce file manager? Just not see any options for this..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: This seems like it existed in the 6.x branch of the module as a "Box View", but in 7.x it looks like it's been dropped. See [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/849590) for the 6.x discussion. And there's a [ticket for 7.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/2804497) too, with 0 activity.

Edit: Serhiy found out that for D7 there's a template file which can be modified to display thumbnails instead of a list.

Comment: Actually, for a drupal 7 it's not hard to do and it can be implemented by change a tpl file, but for drupal 8 there is no template file, this working with a javascript.
I thinking that is not difficult to do for a drupal 8, i'm trying create a patch for this module, but the main problem that i can't take a correct url for the item for using it as 'src' of <img> tag. Stuck with this)